# Seperator / divider beetween date and time (php,mySql)

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to add a separator - between "long date" and  $row->lastlogin, so that the date seems easier to me.

Now it shows: 2022-05-10 01:02:55
Instead:      2022-05-10 - 01:02:55

```
<td><?php echo Date::doDate("long_date", $row->lastlogin);?></td>
```

Any ideas? Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: What contains `$row->lastlogin` ?

Answer (score 0):

You should to look what implement `doDate` function in `Date` class (it's look as custom class in your code), but any case you can just apply `str_replace`

```
echo str_replace(' ', ' - ', Date::doDate("long_date", $row->lastlogin));
```

[PHP sandbox](https://phpize.online/sql/mysql57/undefined/php/php81/ada7de14ac4bdf19405dc97ca6ea34d8/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I try it, but the divider does not appear .. why?

Comment: As Slava Rozhnev mentioned, look for date class. From there you will need to write the split function. Obviously you are in an Admin environment, while you should see date.class.php or anything similar in your libraries.